# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '__app__'

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

I get this unusual error when using the function multiprocessing in Azure function:

```
def multireader(par1, par2): 
        results = []
        jobs = []
        for i in range(5):
            p = multiprocessing.Process(target=myfunction, args=((par1, par2),))
            jobs.append(p)
            p.start()
async def main_(msg: func.ServiceBusMessage):
  multireader(par1, par2)
```

When I run process p.start(), I get this error:

```
Exception has occurred: ModuleNotFoundError       (note: full exception trace is shown but execution is paused at: <module>)
No module named '__app__'
  File "C:\Python38\Lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 126, in _main
    self = reduction.pickle.load(from_parent)
  File "C:\Python38\Lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 116, in spawn_main
    exitcode = _main(fd, parent_sentinel)
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module> (Current frame)
```

Does anyone have an idea how to solve this?

my files for script:

- Main.py --> my function
- Function.json
- *init*.py --> empty

Comment: Hi, Any idea ?  for this problem

Comment: what are `myfunction`,  `par1`, and `par2`? likely one of these is not being un-pickled properly from the main process, causing the crash. Likely one of them is or uses something non-picklable. (see [What can be pickled and unpickled?](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html#what-can-be-pickled-and-unpickled))

Comment: this is an example of a function with parameters, they work fine outside of multi or in threadpool option works fine too

Comment: By "what are they" I mean to say please post the content of the function, and what the type is of the arguments. They all need to be sent to the child process via `pickle`, and not all functions or types are pickle-able

Comment: More specifically, the module `__app__` is not being found and something in your function or args requires it. Is this a flask/django application? It would be very helpful if you could create a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)